# Barcode number representation

Tags: c#

I'm creating a barcode application and when I google to know about barcode I found something that I did not understand and it is the odd left, even left and right digits for example the EAN-13 barcode includes the following

```
OddLeft = new String[] { "0001101", "0011001", "0010011", "0111101",
                                          "0100011", "0110001", "0101111", "0111011",
                                          "0110111", "0001011" };

EvenLeft = new String[] { "0100111", "0110011", "0011011", "0100001",
                                           "0011101", "0111001", "0000101", "0010001",
                                           "0001001", "0010111" };

Right = new String[] { "1110010", "1100110", "1101100", "1000010",
                                        "1011100", "1001110", "1010000", "1000100",
                                        "1001000", "1110100" };
```

Where every string within the string array represents a number from 0 to 9.
How can decimal 0 equals "0001101" in odd left or "0100111" in even left or "1110010" in right. How did they calculate it?
I know the binary representation of decimal 0 and none of the 3 representations above represents a binary represetation of decimal 0.
I read about parity bits too and I found the none of the 3 representations above represents odd or even parity bits of decimal 0.

Is those representations above are standard fixed representation? or there is a way or a calcuation performed to obtain such representation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29

Answer (score 0):

See the zeroes and ones as black or white "modules". Every digit is represented by four bars of with 1 to 4 modules, for a total of 7 modules. There are also fixed bars, one module each.

Here is a complete code:

[image]

Comment: I just need to know how the decimal 0 is represented as 0001101. Decimal 0 binary representation is 00000000, So how did they get the 0001101 representation I hope that my question is clearly understood

Comment: 0001101 is not a binary number, it is 3-2-1-1 modules. Actually, these are the thicknesses in unary base.

Comment: What do you mean by 3 2 1 1 modules? I know that 0 is a white bar and 1 is a black bar so 0001101 while be represented as 3 white consecutive bars then 2 black consecutive bars then a white bar then a black bar. But what is the 3 2 1 1 modules